# How to toggle grid lines that are displayed in wireframe mode?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, edit-mode, wireframe

I'm following a Blender Guru tutorial on how to make a coffee cup. When looking at the cup in wireframe with xray & edit mode on, his screen has no extra gridlines between the vertices/face. Unlike mine which adds gridlines between everything. How do I remove them?

My screen:
[image]

Blender Guru:
[image]

I'm using Blender 2.82. This is the tutorial in I'm referencing https://youtu.be/7w-m13ykLN8?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&t=429

Comment: did you apply the sub.division modifier? it seems your geometry is more complex than the tutorial one

Comment: disable the Subdivision Surface modifier visibility

Comment: @Sanbaldo It's not applied yet and I don't think I've added more geometry than in the tutorial (unless I did by mistake?). However thanks for your comment, it made me check the subdivision modifier and realised I can change viewport setting and the Realtime & Edit Mode displays and using these I can reduce or remove the gridlines. Still can't get it looking exactly the same as in the tutorial but it helps.

Comment: @moonboots Thanks just tried that and it seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

What you see is the *Subdivision Surface* modifier effect on your mesh. Disable its visibility, or, as Frederik Steinmetz suggests, enable the *Optimal Display* option, but in that case keep in mind that you won't see the real mesh but its deformation through the modifier.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. I think ticking "Optimal Display" would suit best in this situation, since in the YT screenshot, the mod is active.

Comment: the problem with Optimal Display is that you don't see the real mesh topology. How do you know it is activated in the screenshot?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell, bc. one screenshot is in edit and one in object mode. The mod. is visible in the YT screenshot, so I assumed it's supposed to be on, then I usually use optimal display.

Comment: Ok, edited  ;)  seems a bit tricky to use this option though...

Comment: it looks like he doesn't use it, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w-m13ykLN8&feature=youtu.be&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&t=429#t=49s

Comment: I'll just believe you :)

Comment: moonboots & @Frederik Steinmetz thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Blender Guru used Blender version 2.81.12 in the mentioned tutorial, while you use a newer version where as there are some (more then 2 ways to change the amount of displayed wireframe geometry). Mentioned wireframe display, Simplify *override* as well as display options of modifiers and most likely some i don't even know.

I believe that the easiest way for you should be to activate the **Optimal Display** option in the subdivision modifier.
[image]

I tried version 2.81.12 and 2.82 where the option was off, while in 2.83 the **Optimal Display** was on by default.

I can't be 100% sure if Andrew Price activated the mode without showing it, but such things are so small and happen often enough off screen.

That said, the **Optimal Display** should solve your situation.
Also, this option affects each object with the modifier separately.

Comment: Thank you for the response. That helps clear it up a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Overlay (next to Xray mode) and click the down button; under Geometry, you will see Wireframe (underneath it would be face orientation). On the side of wireframe you will see the value of 1. If you change that to 0.500, it will reduce the number of lines you see in wireframe mode.